# CSS to target li inside ul inside li

Tags: html, css

I've looked through several DBs but I haven't found the answer that matches or works for my scenarios, so I'm turning to the experts, or at least the more experienced. I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS. I'm trying to figure out how to target an li inside of a ul, that's inside of an li, under a ul. Sort of like a drop down menu, where the main header has a submenu with more options. I don't want to add more classes or id's. I've tried the following versions to apply some basic CSS to it, but I can't seem to get it to target it:

```
    #header-nav ul li
    li ul li a
    li#header-nav ul li
```

Even descendants doesn't seem to work (or it may be that I'm not doing it correctly?)

HTML:

```
 <ul id="header-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test Submenu </a>
      <ul>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 1 </a> </li>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I am attempting to target the Test 1 and Test 2 lines. Is there a way I can do this? I'm tapped on formats to make it work. I just want to change the font size of those two lines. I know it would be easier to add the classes or IDs but I am trying to avoid them where possible as I'm trying to understand the whole child, descendants, targeting thing better.

Comment: You're going to need to use something like [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child), [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), and [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to do this. I suggest researching those. You could also alter the HTML to add classes or ids to make it easier to target specific sections of the DOM.

Comment: I'll look into the last-child, first-child, nth-child. Thanks for the suggestion. As I said in my original post, I'm looking to learn the targeting before I start working with classes and IDs. I know it would make it easier to add them but I'm trying to understand this part before going to the easier side of things. Thanks for the suggestion. Any other advice you can impart is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second version (`li ul li a { ... } `) should work to address those "Test 1" and "Test 2" links 8and nothing else in the code you posted). If it doesn't, the problem has to be in some part of the code which you * didn't* post.

Comment: Hi Johannes, That's what I thought according to w3schools and several other DBs, but when I use it, it seems to have no effect on the text's font size when I use percentages. If I use ems or px values, it works, but I'd like to stick with percentages as I'm working on learning to code toward mobile and responsive sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like that

```css
#header-nav li > ul > li a {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="header-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test Submenu </a>
      <ul>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 1 </a> </li>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
      <a href="#">Test Submenu </a>
      <ul>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 1 </a> </li>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
      <a href="#">Test Submenu </a>
      <ul>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 1 </a> </li>
        <li> > <a href="#"> Test 2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Adel, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it on my code. For some reason, the background color changes but it doesn't seem to change the font size. Is there a reason this would be working partially?

Comment: run the code snippet now and check it out and you can just add `font-size: 2rem;` any value for the `font-size`

Comment: I saw your edit Adel. Is there a way I can keep percentage instead em? I did font-size:80% and it didn't have the correct effect.

Comment: yea just use `font-size:80%;` i believe if you don't define a `font-size` for your `body/html` this 80% will be 14px but i'm sure if you used percentage it will also work fine

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Adel. I tried the latest version you posted but it's still not changing the font-size. I can change any other CSS but not the font size. I checked to make sure I haven't defined any other font sizes anywhere else. I even tried to use !important to override it. But nothing I do seems to have any effect on the font size. I've been able to change the alignment, color, bg color, but not the size. It's very strange.

Comment: i saw in your code you wrote `li#header-nav` this is wrong make sure to make it `#header-nav`

Comment: I was under the impression at the time that it would work the same as a .classname like p.classname (where classname is the actual class name). But then I realized that was wrong as well. It doesn't work with IDs.

Comment: What's really annoying me on this is when I use the inspector in firefox, it tells me the CSS rule I put in for those links is active. If it's active, why isn't it changing anything?

Comment: can you please paste this line of code because I'm sure there is something wrong with your typing if you have the same markup that you gived me it should be like that  `#header-nav li > ul > li a`

Comment: Adel, I copied the line #header-nav li > ul > li a, and pasted it into my CSS. It's still not changing the font size.

Comment: Ok, so it turned out there was an issue with the environment I was working in. It didn't have to do with the code itself but the application that I was running. I was in a site called Codio. It was having major issues and one of them was causing my code to check as incorrect when it was displaying correctly. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

---

> *"...I don't want to add more classes or id's.... I am attempting to target the Test 1 and Test 2 lines. Is there a way I can do this?"*

---

## Answer

---

Yes. But we must know some rules. CSS is declarative and its basic foundation are rules.

---

### [Casscading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works)

---

- **The flow of CSS is a cascade of rulesets that take higher priority than the rulestes that have preceded them**. From top, (less priority but wider influence due to inheritance,) to the bottom (higher priority but less influence due to how inheritance works in the same cascading direction (parent to child.))
- **The closer a ruleset is to the element it represents, the higher a ruleset chances of overriding the styles of the rulesets that have preceded it.**

  ---

  #### Styles

  ---

  **External Stylesheets:** Normal priority, most maintainable, greatest scope -- unlimited amount of pages.

  **Page Location:** Top of `<head>` tag.

  **Example:** `<link href="https://style.com/path/to/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

  ---

  **Inline Style Block:** Higher priority, maintainable, limited scope -- a single page.

  **Page Location:** Bottom of `</head>` tag.

  **Example:** `<style> selector { propertyName: propertyValue } ...</style>`

  ---

  **Inline Style Attribute:** Highest priority, least maintainable, least scope -- limited to a single tag.

  **Page Location:** In a tag.

  **Example:** `<div style="propertyName: propertyValue"></div>`

---

### [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

---

- **The rules of Specificity are the only means of avoiding the cascading rule.** This is the reason when we add a ruleset with `!important` after the Bootstrap CSS file and still have no success in overriding any style. Here's a CSS ruleset:

  ```
  selector {propertyName: propertyValue}
            ⎱                         ⎰
                 Declaration Block
  ```

  Each CSS Selector has a measurable quality called Specificity. It is the measure of how specific a selector's declaration is as opposed to other selectors that share one or more properties and are used by a common element or group of elements. From that conflict, it is resolved by allowing the ruleset with the selector of the greatest specificity to override the styles of the other rulesets with its own styles. Should conflicting rulesets have selectors of equal specicity, then the rules of cascading apply (which ruleset is furthest from the top).

---

- Specificity of a selector is measured by 4 separate numbers. From left (greatest) to right (least):

  1. Being an inline style attribute. A single point in this category overrides all other categories that follow it. The only thing that can override it is `!important` ***unless*** of course it has an `!important` as well. If that's the case, then we can use the Grand Equalizer: JavaScript.
  2. **`#ID`**. Having an **`#ID`** in a selector overrides everything except `!important` and inline style attributes.
  3. **`.CLASS`**. Having **`.Class`**(es), **`[Attributes]`**, and **`:Pseudo-class`**(es) in a selector overrides **`<Element Tags>`** and **`::Pseudo-elements`**.
  4. **`<Element Tags>`** and **`::Pseudo-elements`**, very general thus the least in specificity.

  Go to this page for an [**Online Specificity Calculator**](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

---

If there's no dynamic elements added in the path then this'll work:

```
    #header-nav li:last-of-type ul li a {
      font-size: 48px;
    }
```

There's 3 identical fragments of the layout -- each using a different relative unit of measurement (`rem`, `em`, `%`) at the equivalent distance of 48px (3 times the default of `16px` = `1rem` = `1em` = `100%`. Each fragment also shows how **specificity** and **`!important`** are used to make styles from frameworks like Bootstrap CSS so invincible.

---

### Demo

---

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Consolas;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

b {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: tomato;
}

i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #A3CF65;
}


/* A */


/* 0,1,1,4 ⭐ */

#header-navA li:last-of-type ul li a {
  font-size: 3rem !important;
}


/* 0,1,0,4 */

#header-navA li ul li a {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
}


/* B */


/* 0,2,1,4 ⭐ */

#header-navB#header-navB li:last-of-type ul li a {
  font-size: 3em;
}


/* 0,1,1,4 */

#header-navB li:last-of-type ul li a {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/* C */


/*  */

#header-navC li:last-of-type ul li a {
  font-size: 300% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta chrset='utf-8'>

</head>

<body>
  <ul id="header-navA">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <b>A</b> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i>!important &amp; Specificity Test</i> </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <b>3rem</b> > <a href="#"> Test A1 </a> </li>
        <li> <b>3rem</b> > <a href="#"> Test A2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <ul id="header-navB">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <b>B</b> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i>Specificity Test</i> </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <b>3em</b> > <a href="#"> Test B1 </a> </li>
        <li> <b>3em</b> > <a href="#"> Test B2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <ul id="header-navC">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <b>C</b> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i>!important &amp; Inline Test</i> </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <b>300%</b> > <a href="#" style='font-size:200%;'> Test C1 </a> </li>
        <li> <b>200%</b> > <a href="#" style='font-size:200% !important'> Test C2 </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```